# What's the best way in Drupal to load additional ie.css sheets for Internet explorer 6,7 and 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

What's the best way in Drupal to load additional ie.css sheets for Internet explorer 6,7 and 8 ?

Should I add these lines on top of the page ?

I.e.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link href="http://.../sites/all/themes/zen/zen/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have will work only for ie 8. You need

```
<!--[if IE]>
    link href="http://.../sites/all/themes/zen/zen/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

More information you can find [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: @Sotiris Yes sure.. So it is fine to add these lines. I was wondering if this is the best way to recognize them.

Comment: @Sotiris ok, one last thing. Is there a way to embed the same code if the browser is IE6 or IE7 ? In other words, can I use or operator ? Something like this: [if IE 7 || 8] ?

Comment: my above code work for all ie. If you want to for ie 7,8 you can use <!--[if gte IE 7]> gte means great than & equal. you can also use gt that means grater than. lt = lower than, lte = lower than & equal

Comment: @Sotiris I've actually used [if IE7 ]> and it works also for IE6 (I thought only IE7

Comment: hm..strange. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx and compare with yours. Maybe there is a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles is a project that allows you to define conditional files in your theme's info file.